# ansible lookup pipe insert host name?

Tags: ansible

In ansible I use following to insert date into file that is created by ansible:

```
log_path: c:\ansible_wu{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d') }}.txt
```

Is there a way to insert host name of in front of the date as well?
so file would look something like this:`servername_wu20180518.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the value {{ansible_hostname}}.